# Navigation Controller showing black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I created new ios project, and all I did I went to main.storybord and i embeded it in navigation controller.I get black screen, and i cannot drag anything to the view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Did you set your Navigation Controller as Initial View Controller?

Comment: just set it as an initial view controller

Answer (score 2):

I got it whatever you have done in question, you have to follow the whatever [@iYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407943/3840908) said in his answer but is your case you drag and drop the `Navigationcontroller` and give it `segue` to the `UIviewController`. So in this case `Navigationcontroller` does not get the root viewController and shows you black screen.

[image]

**UI Output:**

[image]

use this code in your `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   return true
}
```

Comment: He wants it in navigation controller

Comment: @iYoung Yeah! as he said **1)** Create new profile **2)** Embed VC and run project.
He need to set `storyboardID` also.

Answer (score 2):

This is how your storyboard should look like. This has nothing to do with code.

[image: Storyboard view]

How to Embed Navigation Controller

[image: Embed in navigation controller]

Comment: i don't think the issue is in embedding navigation controller

Comment: We can't tell the issue without the complete knowledge of the person has implemented. This was just the step I formed as per he mentioned & this way worked so I provided him this as answer so that he can try.